# Trouble with properly converting String to Int with SQL, C#, ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to update a table with a stored procedure in C# and ASP.NET.

I have a table with a self increment value `@ticketnumber`.

I also have a stored procedure that inserts data and creates the next value of the ID.

I have another stored procedure that is supposed to update this table.

My initial issue is that I kept getting the error

> cannot implicitly convert type string to int

I then messed around a bit and got the error to go away. When I run my code, I'll input the value, but Visual Studio will then throw the "Input String Was Not in the Correct Format" error

To clarify, my stored procedure to insert works just fine, but I cannot use the `ID` value to update it.

Here is my code for my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcUpdateTicket]
    @fname nvarchar(50),
    @lname nvarchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @severityID bigint,
    @statusID bigint,
    @departmentID bigint,
    @issuetype bigint,
    @issuedesc nvarchar(500),
    @ticketnumber bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE supporticket
    SET fname = @fname,
        lname = @lname,
        email = @email,
        severityID = @severityID,
        statusID = @statusID,
        departmentID = @departmentID,
        issuetype = @issuetype,
        issuedesc = @issuedesc
    WHERE
        ticketnumber = @ticketnumber

    SET @ticketnumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN @ticketnumber
END
```

Here is my C# code to update:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TrackIT
{
    public class UpdateTicket
    {
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int statusID { get; set; }
        public string issuedesc { get; set; }
        public int severityID { get; set; }
        public int issuetype { get; set; }
        public int departmentID { get; set; }
        public int ticketnum { get; set; }

        public void Update()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcUpdateTicket"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramFName = new SqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    paramFName.Value = fname;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFName);

                    SqlParameter paramLName = new SqlParameter("@lName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    paramLName.Value = lname;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLName);

                    SqlParameter paramEmail = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    paramEmail.Value = email;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEmail);

                    SqlParameter paramSeverity = new SqlParameter("@severityID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    paramSeverity.Value = severityID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSeverity);

                    SqlParameter paramStatus = new SqlParameter("@statusID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    paramStatus.Value = statusID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStatus);

                    SqlParameter paramDepartment = new SqlParameter("@departmentID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    paramDepartment.Value = departmentID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDepartment);

                    SqlParameter paramissuedesc = new SqlParameter("@issuedesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);
                    paramissuedesc.Value = issuedesc;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramissuedesc);

                    SqlParameter paramissuetype = new SqlParameter("@issuetype", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    paramissuetype.Value = issuetype;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramissuetype);

                    SqlParameter paramticketnum = new SqlParameter("@ticketnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    paramticketnum.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    paramticketnum.Value = ticketnum;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramticketnum);

                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = con;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        int tickID = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ticketnumber"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Dispose();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And lastly, where I implement my update

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        upd.ticketnum = Int32.Parse(ticketnumberbox.ToString().Trim());
        upd.fname = fnamebox.Text;
        upd.lname = lnamebox.Text;
        upd.email = emailbox.Text;
        upd.severityID = Convert.ToInt32(listSeverity.SelectedValue);
        upd.statusID = Convert.ToInt32(liststatus.SelectedValue);
        upd.departmentID = Convert.ToInt32(ListDept.SelectedValue);
        upd.issuetype = Convert.ToInt32(Listissuetype.SelectedValue);
        upd.issuedesc = BoxDetails.Text;

        upd.Update();

        uForm.Visible = false;
        UpdateSuccess.Visible = true;
    }
```

My problem lies with creating a textbox for ticketnumber and being able to use that user input to then update the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're main problem seems to be: you need to **pass in** the `ticketnumber` to your update stored procedure - and the update will **NOT** produce a new `ID` - you're just **updating** an existing row - so using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and returning an ID is pointless here.....

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to convert the control `ticketnumberbox` to string instead of converting its value to string.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what type ticketnumberbox is but if it is a text box you'll need to parse the value of the Text property instead of calling `.ToString()` on the object.

try: `upd.ticketnum = Int32.Parse(ticketnumberbox.Text.Trim());`

EDIT
I think there are a couple issues first your @ticketnumber param probably needs to be both input and output.
Change this line:

```
paramticketnum.Direction = ParameterDirection.OutPut;
```

To:

```
paramticketnum.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

The other issue is in your stored procedure.  You're setting your output to
`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` this will always return `DBNULL` since you're just updating and not inserting.  Which is why this line fails:

```
int tickID = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ticketnumber"].Value.ToString());
```

Try:

```
if (!(cmd.Parameters["@ticketnumber"].Value is DBNull))
{
    int tickID = Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@ticketnumber"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Now just change `SET @ticketnumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` with another method to get the value you need.

Comment: Well that stopped the initial message, but now my UpdateTicket is throwing the exception message with the same error, input string incorrect format. ticketnumberbox is a textbox reading in an integer by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
ticketnumberbor.Text.ToString();
```

try to do this.
Or contact me via email with your TeamViewer ID and password, I will try to help you. My email is xazratbek@gmail.com. I just want to trace your code and it's values